# Kotlin method chaining to process strings in a list

Tags: string, list, kotlin, method-chaining

I have a list of strings I get as a result of splitting a string. I need to remove the surrounding quotes from the strings in the list. Using method chaining how can I achieve this? I tried the below, but doesn't work.Says type interference failed.

```
val splitCountries: List<String> = countries.split(",").forEach{it -> it.removeSurrounding("\"")}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) doesn't return the value you generate in it, it's really just a replacement for a `for` loop that performs the given action. What you need here is [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html):

```
val splitCountries: List<String> = countries.split(",").map { it.removeSurrounding("\"") }
```

Also, a single parameter in a lambda is implicitly named `it`, you only have to name it explicitly if you wish to change that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Quick question. This removes the surrounding quotes when there is just on item in the list. When there are multiple items, it doesn't remove the surrounding double quotes. Any idea why?

Comment: Using it.replace("\"","") worked out for me, any idea why removeSurrounding didn't do it?

Comment: Did you have the quotes around the entire list, such as `"Country1, Country2, Country3"`? In that case, you'd have to `removeSurrounding` first, and then split & map.

Comment: How I have them is, ""country1"", ""country2"" etc. in the list

Comment: If you have a space in there between the items, that would be the issue. `removeSurrounding` will only remove characters if it finds the same one both at the very beginning and very end of the string. So you'd have to get rid of the spaces first, for example with a `trim`: `it.trim().removeSurrounding("\"")`